# Thumbs_up Gem, a Little issue with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I came across this link the other day and I decided to implement this voting system through ajax: [JQuery + thumbs_up gem render vote count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176392/jquery-thumbs-up-gem-render-vote-count) . But the problem is I pretty much followed it step by step but it seems as though the ajax isn't working. Can anyone help? Thank you!

**Micropost Controller**

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController

  def vote_up
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_exclusively_for(@micropost)
  end

  def vote_down
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_exclusively_against(@micropost)
  end

end
```

**votecount.html.erb**

```
<div class='Counter'>
<span class='CounterNum'><%= @micropost.votes_for %></span>
<a href="#" class='CounterButton b2' updown="up" theid="123">
<span class='CounterIcon'></span>
</a>
<a href="#" class='CounterButton b2' updown="down" theid="123">
<span class='CounterIcon'></span>
</a>
</div>
```

**votecount.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".CounterButton").click(function() {
        var val = $(this).attr('updown');
        var theid = $(this).attr('theid');
        if (val == "up") {
            console.log('up');
        } else {
            console.log('down');
        }
    });​
});
```

Comment: Is your click handler getting called?

Comment: @muistooshort I am unsure how to go about this, still quite noobish to jquery, sorry but thank you for your help!

Comment: You could just add a `console.log(...)` call inside the click handler and watch what shows up in the JavaScript console.

Comment: @muistooshort not to sound needy but can you point to which area to add this in? Sorry for the questions, been working on this for literally hours and can't do anything right

Comment: You can put it right after `$(".CounterButton").click(function(){`, just a simple `console.log('click handler called')` to see if it gets called when you expect it to.

Comment: @muistooshort hmm it isn't doing anything in particular, on the micropost there are two buttons rather than one showing the ajax not working, hmmm would it be possible that I am missing anything cause everything I have for voting is up there

Comment: That basically works (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tfhS3/). Are you adding that HTML after the page is loaded?

Comment: @muistooshort I edited it above to what you wrote, is that how it should look also if you are talking about the Counter Div HTML, it is place like so on the micropost `<%= render :partial => "microposts/votecount" %>` hmmm I feel as though the HTML is out of place because the up and down buttons are on the page at the same time and yet still doesn't do anything

Comment: Are you including `votecount.js` anywhere?

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, I placed it in the assests/javascript and included it in the application

Comment: But are you sure that it is being run? A quick `console.log('yes')` after `$(document).ready(function(){` might be helpful. Then watch the JavaScript console when you load your page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working fine for me .. Just have look at this [http://jsfiddle.net/GLVQe/](http://jsfiddle)

Make sure you added jQuery library file before this jQuery code.